# MVC: Custom login page uses same field validators as Register page incorrectly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, model

New to MVC. Using Entity Framework and database first.

**Problem**

-Register page has fields for username, password, confirm password, and e-mail with validators.

-Login page has username and password fields also with validators. Login page asks for confirm password and e-mail when it shouldn't.

**Goal**

-Fix this, and maybe learn some proper way of using models in the meantime. I have read many articles and seen many videos but a lot use code first, which I am not using. Very confusing to me.

**CODE**

My User database doesn't have a Confirm Password field so I made a model...

```
namespace StoreFront.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(RegisterViewModel))]
    public partial class User
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My CustomerBaseViewModel has the LoginViewModel and RegisterViewModel that my views should be using...

```
public class LoginViewModel
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Username")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Username")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords must match")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Email")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$",
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

I have two separate controllers...one for login and one for register. Not sure if you need to look at it but I added anyway

```
public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(User user)
        {
            using (StoreFrontContext db = new StoreFrontContext())
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return View();
                }
                else
                {
                    var usr = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.ToLower() == user.UserName.ToLower() && u.Password == user.Password).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (usr != null)
                    {
                        Session["Username"] = usr.UserName.ToString();
                        Session["UserID"] = usr.UserName.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password is incorrect.");
                    }
                }
            }
                return View();
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class RegisterController : Controller
    {
        StoreFrontContext db = new StoreFrontContext();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(User account)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (db)
                {
                    bool duplicate = true;

                    foreach (var name in db.Users)
                    {
                        if (account.UserName.ToLower() == name.UserName.ToString().ToLower())
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username already exists in database!");
                            duplicate = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            duplicate = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!duplicate)
                    {
                        account.IsAdmin = false;
                        account.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                        db.Users.Add(account);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        ModelState.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Login Index() View uses `@model StoreFront.Models.LoginViewModel` and Register Index() View uses `@model StoreFront.Models.RegisterViewModel`

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong, but I believe it's what is being passed through the View or the controller. I'm still not very familiar with the Model part of MVC yet..been very struggling on that, so any pointers on that would also help. Any help would be strongly appreciated!!

Comment: I have narrowed it down to MetadataType(typeof(RegisterViewModel))] part of the code when I am making a partial view of the User.cs and adding ConfirmPassword field...The RegisterViewModel, when I substituted it for LoginViewModel, lost the e-mail validation, so putting RegisterViewModel in there is causing the problem, but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: your `HttpPost` actions should accept the same model type your view is using.. Register should be `public ActionResult Index(RegisterViewModel account)`.. then rewrite your code to not loop thru db.Users but use `bool duplicate = db.Users.Any(a => a.UserName == account.UserName);`

Comment: I have done that, and now the line `db.Users.Add(account)` in RegisterController gives me the error `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'StoreFront.Models.RegisterViewModel' to 'StoreFront.Models.User'`

Comment: thats because you need to use something like `db.Users.Add(new StoreFront.Models.User {UserName = account.UserName,  EmailAddress  = account.EmailAddress, Password = functionToEncryptPassword(account.Password)});`

Comment: Ohh okay, It was working fine with the way I had it before, but I need to manually add everything now, will come back if I have anymore problems.....Edit: make this an answer and I will accept it, it works! Thanks

Comment: if your only problem is the login action you can change the model there to LoginViewModel and it should work the same

Comment: `Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.` is what I get at `db.SaveChanges();` with the fixes. When I remove that line there is no error, but isn't added to database

Comment: If this code is for a real system with real users, then you need to learn a lot more about authentication. Storing passwords in clear in the database is a recipe for disaster. If this is just a play thing then ignore that :)

Comment: I was using hash and encoding as some basic authentication, but what we are currently doing is just a small test application so the coordinator said go head and don't worry about authentication yet. Thanks though :D